# Correct Pass - Hired!

Tags: mazes, network

It seems that I got offered a new *(redacted text)*, so this is likely to be the **last entry of my journal**. My job will be *(redacted text)*!

The main building is just like the others. On my first day, I came into **Reception** with my **orange** pass. (They have hardened the exits here, so I left with an **orange** pass at the **end of the day** too.)

Then it was straight off to **Inaugurations** - where I was *(redacted text)*! I needed the **orange** pass for that - I was nearly late for it on my first day too - having to switch my pass more than once only to end up with an orange one again..

After getting inaugurated, I was sent to **Induction**, having to pick up a **blue** pass on the way, where I was met by a charming young man who then sat me through an hour of the most boring *(redacted text)* I have ever witnessed.

Then off to the one room found in every *(redacted text)*! A quick slurp of uncle Joe at the *(redacted text)*. It's really great there - but they serve **blue** pass holders only, and there's a long queue in and out of it.

Then I rushed through *(redacted text)* at the **Briefing Room** with a **green** *(redacted text)* though I nearly got lost. My line manager *(redacted text)*.

Towards the end of the day, I visited my new office – the *(redacted text)* which needs a **blue** pass. Then it was straight back and out the front door at the end of a *(redacted text)* day.

[image]

Comment: I believe this is far the best of the set.

Comment: I'm imagining all these redacted parts as vulgarities....

Comment: @msh210, Haha.. we can neither confirm not deny...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying my assumptions about the rules, and observations from the previous puzzle:

> - The squares on the grid edges are the doors with a pass colour that you need to pass from one room to another.
>  - The paired arrows in each cell represent exchanging your pass for a different colour.
>  - Multiple swaps can be performed in a room.

Observations:

> - If a room has only one door of a particular colour, and no exchange-arrows with that colour, then that room represents a dead-end for that pass colour.
>
>  - If a room has only one exchange arrow with a particular colour, and no doors of that colour, then that exchange-arrow can be ignored.
>
>  - These rules can be applied iteratively, and a number of paths (and some entire rooms) can be marked as unusable dead-ends.
>
>  With all those options crossed out, we end up with the following map:
>  [image]

On to the puzzle:

> The first few moves from reception are forced
>  E (To the Canteen)
>  Swap Orange-Red
>  E
>  Swap Red-Yellow-Green-Blue-Purple-Orange
>  N
>  Swap Orange-Red
>  W
>  Swap Red-Purple
>  W
>  Swap Purple-Blue
>  We now have a choice here, but the quickest was to Inaugurations is:
>  N, N
>  Swap Blue-Green
>  W,N,N
>  Swap Green-Blue
>  S
>  Swap Blue-Purple
>  N,E
>  Swap Purple-Blue-Yellow
>  E,E
>  Swap Yellow-Red-Blue-Orange-Purple-Green
>  N
>  Swap Green-Yellow-Blue-Red
>  W (To Inaugurations)
>  Swap Red-Green-Orange, and we have the right pass for our first goal.

> This is a dead end, so we have to backtrack several moves before going anywhere new.
>  Swap Orange-Green-Red
>  E
>  Swap Red-Blue-Yellow-Green
>  S
>  Swap Green-Purple-Orange-Blue-Red-Yellow
>  W,W
>  Swap Yellow-Blue-Purple
>  W,S
>  Swap Purple-Blue
>  N
>  Swap Blue-Green
>  S
>  Here we diverge from our outbound route
>  W,S,W
>  Swap Green-Yellow
>  W,S
>  Swap Yellow-Purple
>  S,S (To Briefing Room, briefly)
>  W,W,N (To Induction, but we haven't got the right coloured pass yet, and can't get it here.)
>  Swap Purple-Green-Red
>  S
>  Swap Red-Yellow-Orange-Green-Blue
>  N (Back to Induction, with the correct pass this time for our second goal).

> Again, we are in a dead-end and need to backtrack.
>  S
>  Swap Blue-Green-Orange-Yellow-Red
>  N
>  Swap Red-Green-Purple
>  S,E,E (Through the Briefing Room again)
>  N,N
>  There are other possible routes from here, but it is quicker to continue backtracking.
>  Swap Purple-Yellow
>  N,E
>  Swap Yellow-Green
>  E,N
>  Now we diverge again.
>  Swap Green-Blue-Red-Purple-Yellow
>  S
>  Swap Yellow-Blue-Purple
>  E,S
>  Swap Purple-Yellow
>  E,S
>  Swap Yellow-Orange-Red
>  S (To Reception)
>  Swap Red-Green-Yellow
>  E (To Canteen)
>  Swap Yellow-Green-Blue and we have reached our third goal.

> Again, this is a dead-end, so backtracking is required.
>  The route here isn't entirely forced, but we've already passed through the Briefing Room, and the simplest way back there is to retrace our steps with a minor diversion at the end to make sure we have the correct pass.
>  Swap Blue-Green-Yellow
>  W (To Reception)
>  Swap Yellow-Green-Red
>  N
>  Swap Red-Orange-Yellow
>  N,W
>  Swap Yellow-Purple
>  N,W
>  Swap Purple-Blue-Yellow
>  N
>  Swap Yellow-Purple-Red-Blue-Green
>  S,W
>  Swap Green-Yellow
>  W,S
>  (Here we diverge from our Induction route.)
>  W
>  Swap Yellow-Green
>  S
>  Swap Green-Blue-Orange
>  S
>  Swap Orange-Blue-Red-Yellow-Green
>  E (To the Briefing Room with the correct pass for our fourth goal.)

> Again, we are in a dead-end, so back we go...
>  W
>  Swap Green-Yellow-Red-Blue-Orange
>  N
>  Swap Orange-Blue-Green
>  N
>  Swap Green-Yellow
>  E,N,E
>  Swap Yellow-Green
>  E,N
>  Here we diverge
>  Swap Green-Blue-Red-Purple-Orange
>  W,W,W
>  Swap Orange-Green-Red-Blue
>  W,S
>  Swap Blue-Purple
>  N,N (To the Broom Cupboard, but lacking the correct pass)
>  N
>  Swap Purple-Red-Blue
>  S (To <strike>our luxurious office</strike>the Broom Cupboard with the correct pass.)

> Finally it's another bunch of backtracking along well-trod paths to find our way to Reception.
>  N
>  Swap Blue-Red-Purple
>  S (through the Broom Cupboard again)
>  S,S
>  Swap Purple-Blue
>  N,E
>  Swap Blue-Red-Green-Orange
>  E,E,E
>  Swap Orange-Purple-Red-Blue-Green
>  E,S,E
>  Swap Green-Blue
>  S,S
>  Swap Blue-Purple
>  E
>  Swap Purple-Green-Red
>  E
>  Swap Red-Orange
>  S
>  Swap Orange-Purple-Blue-Green-Yellow-Red
>  W (To the Canteen)
>  Swap Red-Orange
>  W (Back to Reception finally at the end of a long day.)

Map:

> [image]

Comment: Gold star!. Beautifully done.  I do hope you found this a bit more interesting?  Is it 'tough enough', considering it is, essentially, nothing more than a graphical maze?